# Assigning IPs to multiple virtual machines

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I've been writing script that takes virtual machines from certain vlan defined in csv file and assign them random IP address from chosen IP range.

- For IP range I am using function Get-IPrange downloadable from powershell gallery.
- Problem I cannot find solution for is assigning random IP addresses from my IP range to multiple virtual machines.
- When my array $iparrays contains one ip address it works.
- If I have more machines and therefore more IP addresses in the array it tries to assign same IP address to each virtual machine with following error.

Error:

```
VM           : test-automata-01
ExitCode     : 0
ScriptOutput :
               Invalid mask parameter (10.84.64.203).



VM           : test-automata-02
ExitCode     : 0
ScriptOutput :
               Invalid mask parameter (10.84.64.203).
```

My script:

```
#Loading CSV with vlan list
$vlans = Import-CSV -Path "C:\scripts\Automata\ipchange-vlan.csv"

#IP range for cloned virtual machines
$iprange = Get-IPrange -start 10.84.64.200 -end 10.84.64.254

#Fetching vlans that are supposed to be cloned based on determined clone day (determined in CSV)
$vms = @()
foreach ($vlan in $vlans) 
   {
     #Acquiring list of vlans
     $vms += Get-VDPortgroup $vlan.vlan | Get-VM
   }
$vms

#Count of filtered virtual machines
$ipcount = ($vms).count

#Randomizing IP address
$iparrays = $iprange | Get-Random -Count $ipcount

#Static ip config
$ipmask = "255.255.255.192"
$dgw = "10.84.64.193"
$netcard = "Ethernet0"

foreach ($vm in $vms)
{
    $vmip = Get-VM -Name $vm.Name

foreach ($iparray in $iparrays)
{
$cmd=@"
c:\windows\system32\netsh.exe interface ip set address $netcard static $iparray "255.255.255.192" "10.84.64.193"
c:\windows\system32\netsh.exe interface ipv4 set dns name=$netcard static 8.8.8.8 primary
"@    

Invoke-VMScript -VM $vmip.Name -GuestUser "Administrator" -GuestPassword "Admin123" -ScriptType bat -ScriptText $cmd -Verbose
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, once you have one, you need to drop that from the available IPA list passed in..

For Example (there are of course more elegant ways to do X or Y, but this is just an idea - and untested, as I do not have an environment to perform this use case):

something like this is a loop

```
# Set the Ipa range
([System.Collections.ArrayList]$IpaRange = 200..254 | 
ForEach{"10.84.64.$PSItem"})

# Results
<#
10.84.64.200
10.84.64.201
10.84.64.202
...
#>

$IpaRange.Count 

# Results 
<#
55
#>

$TargetIpa = ''

# Get the first IPA to use
($TargetIpa = Get-Random $IpaRange -Count 1)

# Results
<#
10.84.64.242
#>

If ($IpaRange -contains $TargetIpa)
{
    $IpaRange.Remove("$TargetIpa")
    ($TargetIpa = Get-Random $IpaRange -Count 1)
    $IpaRange.Count
}

# Results
<#
10.84.64.231
54
#>

# Or 
# Set the Ipa range
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$IpaRange = 200..254 | 
ForEach{"10.84.64.$PSItem"}

# First IPA to use
$TargetIpa = Get-Random $IpaRange -Count 1
<#
# First VM IPA 
#Static ip config
$ipmask = $TargetIpa
$dgw = "10.84.64.193"
$netcard = "Ethernet0"
#>

Try
{
    do
    {
        If ($IpaRange -contains $TargetIpa)
        {
            $IpaRange.Remove("$TargetIpa")
            ($TargetIpa = Get-Random $IpaRange -Count 1)

            <#
            #Static ip config
            $ipmask = $TargetIpa 
            $dgw = "10.84.64.193"
            $netcard = "Ethernet0"
            #>

            $IpaRange.Count
        }    
    }
    while ($IpaRange.Count -ne 0)
}
Catch
{Write-Warning -Message 'IP address assignments complete.'}

# Results
<#
10.84.64.233
54
10.84.64.205
53
10.84.64.241
52
...
10.84.64.235
3
10.84.64.214
2
10.84.64.231
1
WARNING: IP address assignments complete.
#>
```